# Windows 10 disable specific input language from switching shortcut

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, input-languages

On Windows 10 I frequently use [Win Key] + Space to switch between input languages which is great. I have 3 input languages installed, so hitting that combination each time switches between each one.

For two of the languages, I use them 99% of the time, whereas the third one I only use 1% of the time, but I still occasionally need to use it. Is it possible to disable the third language (or specific languages for that matter) from being switchable using the [Win Key] +  Space shortcut so I can avoid having to go pass that option each time?

I know I can set specific hotkey combos for each language, but none of them are as quick and easy as using [Win Key] + Space.

Edit: One way of course is to remove the 3rd language, and only install it when I need to. But that is very inconvenient for us superusers and will surely negate all the time previously saved by switching between the main 2 languages using the shortcut keys.